# passing metadata from one activity to the next in an android listview

Tags: android

I understand that there's a set of methods used to pass data from one activity to the next using, but how do I model it from within the activity with the list view?

Example: I have a json object which i use to populate a listview. Each list item has an id. I want to pass the id to the next activity on click. How do I know that listview's item id? I wasn't sure how to attach arbitrary metadata to a listview item and immediately grab it and pass it along.

```
public class StuffListActivity extends ListActivity
{
    private MyApplication application = null;

    /**
     * Called when the activity is first created.
     *
     * @param savedInstanceState the saved instance state
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        application = ((Application) getApplication());
        Requestor req = new Requestor();
        Application.log(listType.toString());
        ArrayList<String> list = req.getStuff(application.getId(), listType);

        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                R.layout.list, R.id.stuff, list);
        setListAdapter(adapter);    
    }

    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) 
    {
        String item = (String) getListAdapter().getItem(position);
        Toast.makeText(this, item + " selected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: If you have custom list item, then u can use any of the component used in it(eg. a TextView) and use its get/set Tag method inside your custom Adapter to store and retrieve id. You can refer more for Tags [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setTag%28java.lang.Object%29)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use **setTag()** and **getTag()** property for list view in Adapter getView() code.. to store and retrieve the data.

Comment: the examples that i see using this have a set amount of things on the pages (textviews, buttons). i am using a dynamic list to populate a listview, so i am unsure how that correlates. my original question has source code for context

Comment: even if you are using dynamic list we can use adapter for populating data use this properties in that. if you are not aware of this let me know and show the code.

Comment: use custom adapter for this... you can do what ever you want with custom adapter.

Comment: can you show an example of this? i see how to do things in particular, using arrayadapters or settag/gettag, but never in combination